# Изменение пути подключения js файлов в сборке react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

появилась проблема при сборке приложения файлы подключаются с слешем впереди

вот так: `"/static/js/main.24ab7a2e.chunk.js"`, а мне по условиям задачи нужно

так: `"static/js/main.24ab7a2e.chunk.js"`, без слеша.

Пробовал в **webpack.config.js** задавать параметр **"publicPath"** и в package.json параметр **"homepage"** но ничего не помогло. В какую сторону еще можно посмотреть?

Содержимое webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        publicPath: 'static/', 

    }
};
```

Comment: добавьте код webpack.config.js в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте сделать alias https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: Ничего не помогло, react я только начал изучать и вебпаком там не пахло оказывается все делают react-scripts которые по умолчанию использовались если создавать начальное приложение в webstorm. Временно решил проблему дополнительной командой которая после build запускается и меняет путь на нужный мне.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй ко так

```
const path = require('path')
path: path.resolve(__dirname,'static')
```